# Warning is shown when hovering mouse over QToolButton actions

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qaction

I have made a `QToolButton` with some actions like :

```
QToolButton * toolBut1 = new QToolButton(this);

actionGroup1 = new QActionGroup(this);
actionGroup1->setExclusive(true);

action1 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon1"),"", actionGroup1);
action1->setCheckable(true);

action2 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon2"),"", actionGroup1);
action2->setCheckable(true);

action3 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon3"),"", actionGroup1);
action3->setCheckable(true);

toolBut1->addAction(action1);
toolBut1->addAction(action2);
toolBut1->addAction(action3);
```

But when I hover the mouse pointer on the actions, some warnings are displayed in the application output :

> QGradient::setColorAt: Color position must be specified in the range 0 to 1

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

P.S. I am using Qt 4.8.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: Did you not port your project to Qt 5? Can you please try 4.8.6 at least?

Comment: I have never used more than one `QAction` per `QToolButton`. Did you maybe meant `QToolBar`?

Answer (score 1):

I set **different names** for these actions and result was that the warning is not shown any more.

```
QToolButton * toolBut1 = new QToolButton(this);

actionGroup1 = new QActionGroup(this);
actionGroup1->setExclusive(true);

action1 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon1"),"act1", actionGroup1);
action1->setCheckable(true);

action2 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon2"),"act2", actionGroup1);
action2->setCheckable(true);

action3 = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/icon3"),"act3", actionGroup1);
action3->setCheckable(true);

toolBut1->addAction(action1);
toolBut1->addAction(action2);
toolBut1->addAction(action3);
```